# Multiple Z-index Elements on One Page

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

Can anyone tell me how this effect is created?

[Link to desired effect](http://evercorewealthmanagement.com/about-us/)

Whereby the header bar and image stay static but as you scroll down the webpage the content area overlaps the image but not the header.

I thought that maybe the header and bg image and content area all have different z-index's but I just cant seem to replicate this effect.

Below is what I have been playing around with locally:

```
<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#head{
    width:2000px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:#666;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
}

#image{
    width:2000px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#F00;
}

#content{
    width:2000px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#090;
}
</style>

<div id="head">HEAD</div>
<div id="image">IMAGE</div>
<div id="content">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: `inspect element` and give it a try

Comment: is It  Parallax design?

Comment: it's called Parallax design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the body (or wrapping element) to have a background with:

```
body { 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

More: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

This forces the background to stay put, even with page scroll.

Then add your content into the body...
It will scroll on by, while the background of the body is static.

EXAMPLE: https://jsfiddle.net/a8qpxzy2/2/

Comment: Yes.. This did it! Thank you.

Comment: Sure! Please help me out and select it as the correct answer! @Pogostick

Comment: More on 'Parallax' here: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites @Pogostick

Answer (score 0):

Here's how they did it.

The `header` and `bg-image` are both fixed. While the `content` is set to `relative`.

`Headers` z-index is 10000 , `bg-image` z-index is 20 and `content` z-index is 2000.

You should know how it works with these informations.